# How to break elements in an array at each comma? python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

So i opened a dataset and in short it looked something like this:

```
list1= ['Adrian,20,5,2000,green', 'Steve,15,6,1997,blue', ...]
trial = np.array(list1)
```

when i tried to print(trial[0][0]) to get Adrian, i only got the A.

So i figured i should make everything that has a comma after it an independent element, please help me  get the output to be:

```
(['Adrian', 20, 5, 2000, 'green'], ['steve', 15, 6, 1997, 'blue'], ...)
```

where print(trial[0]) will give: ['Adrian', 20, 5, 2000, 'green']

and print(trial[0][0]) will give: Adrian

Comment: It looks like your data comes from a CSV that was read incorrectly. Instead of trying to fix the data after reading it incorrectly, consider to read it correctly in the first place. If that is so, you might want to [edit] your question to show the data and how it is read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the split function with a comma as the parameter like this:-

```
list2= ['Adrian,20,5,2000,green', 'Steve,15,6,1997,blue']
list1= []
for i in list2:
    a = i.split(',')
    list1 += [a]
trial = numpy.array(list1)
print(trial[0][0])
```

This will return Adrian.
You will still have to typecast the numbers to integer though, but that's easy to work around.

Comment: can you please offer an example?

Comment: @AdryanZiegler, you're welcome. Again, keep in mind that the numbers in the list are still currently strings, and if you are going to perform operations on them, you need to make sure that they are integers first.

Comment: yes i noticed. is there a way to check using if statement in the loop whether the string can be converted to an integer and if so change it to that integer, else skip to the next element? something like for item in list1: for element in item: if int(element) == true: element = int(element) or maybe add it to another empty list, what do you think? and thanks a lot again i truly appreciate it !!!

Comment: @AdryanZiegler  use "String_number".isnumeric() , it will return true if its a number